# Is there a way to concatenate a django object query from a template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following code:

```
<table id="MyTable" class="highlight responsive-table" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
          {% with columns as columns %}
              {% for columns in columns %}
                <th class="th-sm">{{ columns }}</th>
              {% endfor %}
          {% endwith %}

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for trans in transactions %}
      <tr>
          <td> {{ trans.transactionsequencenumber }}</td>
          <td> {{ trans.posid }}</td>
          <td> {{ trans.transactionnumber }}</td>
      </tr>

    {% endfor %}


  </table>
```

which works for displaying static table data, but the idea is that the columns being iterated are being set via a user preferences model, so the table columns can change depending on the user, theres a possible 90+ columns to choose from, and here is where my issue lays.

pseudo code below to help illustrate my goal:

```
<table id="MyTable" class="highlight responsive-table" >
<thead>
  <tr>
      {% with columns as columns %}
          {% for columns in columns %}
            <th class="th-sm">{{ columns }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endwith %}

  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for trans in transactions %}
  <tr>
      <td> {{ trans.{{columns}} }}</td>
  </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

I've tried simple string concatenation so far, but that just prints the string to the table and not the object data,

any help and/or guidance would be greatly apprecieted.
be kind, this is my first question.

Comment: Can you try coming up with another name other than `columns`? I just don't feel safe using the same name twice.

Comment: I know this isn't the best way for production, but im just prototyping right now, so it will change

Answer (score 0):

For every object that represent a line in the database attribute, you put it into a column. For example:

```html
<tr>
  <th> title </th>
  <th> body </th>
</tr>

{% for post in posts %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{post.title}}</td>
      <td> {{post.body}} </td>
        
  </tr>  
{% endfor %}
```